# apache 2 ssl configuration

Tags: ssl, certificate, apache2

I received the following three sections from RapidSSL

```
Web Server CERTIFICATE
-----------------
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
BLABLABLA 1
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

INTERMEDIATE CA:
---------------------------------------

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
BLABLABLA 2
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
BLABLABLA 3
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

how i can create the 3 files for configure apache like:

SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/conf/ssl.crt/**your_leaf_certificate.crt**

SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/conf/ssl.key/**your_domain_name.key**

SSLCACertificatePath /etc/httpd/conf/ssl.chain/**your_intermediate_chain.crt**

im expecting to find this

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

but can't find it :(

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you have is that you will have to download from CertCentral the certificate bundle. You will have to login into digicert.com, and get your certificates. Click Certificates > Click orders > select order > download cert.

After you download the certificate, you can use this tool called Utility Tool For Windows [Tool](https://www.digicert.com/util/)

After that, you can import your cert into that tool, and you will be able to export it to be able to get a pem file with your key as an individual file.

If you purchased this certificate through a third-party vendor, I will recommend you to get a new CSR and send it to them to make sure they can reissue your certificate.